The error was caused by importing 'mongoose/dist/browser.umd.js' in './config/mongodb/index.ts'
I created my own application on next.js version 14 with mogoose version ^8.4.4 that works well on my local.
I tried to deploy my next application on Vercel but I got this on console:
Failed to compile.
./config/mongodb/index.ts
Dynamic Code Evaluation (e. g. 'eval', 'new Function', 'WebAssembly.compile') not 
allowed in Edge Runtime 
Learn More: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/edge-dynamic-code-evaluation
The error was caused by importing 'mongoose/dist/browser.umd.js' in 
'./config/mongodb/index.ts'.
Import trace for requested module:
./config/mongodb/index.ts
./src/config/auth/auth.providers.ts
./src/config/auth/auth.config.ts
./src/middleware.ts
> Build failed because of webpack errors
 ELIFECYCLE  Command failed with exit code 1.
Error: Command "pnpm run build" exited with 1

and this is my code:
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

interface Cached {
  conn: typeof mongoose | null;
  promise: Promise<typeof mongoose> | null;
}

const cached: Cached = {
  conn: null,
  promise: null,
};

export const connect = async () => {
  try {
    console.log(
      ' ~ connect ~ process.env.DATABASE_URL:',
      process.env.DATABASE_URL,
    );
    if (cached.conn) {
      return cached.conn;
    }
    if (!cached.promise) {
      cached.promise = mongoose
        .connect(process.env.DATABASE_URL ?? '')
        .then(mongoose => {
          return mongoose;
        });
    }

    cached.conn = await cached.promise;
    return cached.conn;
  } catch (error) {
    throw error;
  }
};

export const disconnect = async () => {
  if (cached.conn) {
    try {
      await mongoose.connection.close();
      cached.conn = null;
      cached.promise = null;
      console.log('Disconnected from MongoDB');
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
      throw error;
    }
  }
};

something interesting is that works well the project on my repo but when I tried to deploy on vercel I got this error.
any idea what could be the reason.


Just now work with this type of error.
Problem is middleware - running runtime: "edge", and disallow use some funcs which can be done with runtime: "nodejs",
work for me:
export const config = {
    matcher: "/:path*",
    runtime: "nodejs",
    unstable_allowDynamic: [
        // allows a single file
        "/src/db/lib/dbConnect.js",
        // use a glob to allow anything in the function-bind 3rd party module
        "/node_modules/mongoose/dist/**",
    ],
};

Add this part (change only your lib dest.) to the ned of your middleware file
also check this part of docs
my middleware
success build result
